# Able to execute API call in Postman but getting a 500 response code when I make the call from React Native

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, postman, http-status-code-500

The API call should return either True or False if there is a token or not and I'm getting the correct response when I try in Postman but get a 500 code in React Native.

**My backend code (django rest framework):**

**Spotify token model:**

```
class SpotifyToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    expires_in = models.DateTimeField()
    token_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**View that checks if user is authenticated:**

```
class IsAuthenticated(APIView):
    authentication_class = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_class = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = SpotifyTokenSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        is_authenticated = is_spotify_authenticated(
            self.request.session.session_key)
        return Response({'status': is_authenticated}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**function inside previous View thats checks for token:**

```
def is_spotify_authenticated(session_id):
    tokens = get_user_tokens(session_id)
    if tokens:
        expiry = tokens.expires_in
        if expiry <= timezone.now():
            refresh_spotify_token(session_id)
        return True
    return False
```

**function that gets the token:**

```
def get_user_tokens(session_id):
    user_tokens = SpotifyToken.objects.filter(user_id=session_id)
    if user_tokens.exists():
        return user_tokens[0]
    else:
        return None
```

**My frontend code (React Native):**

```
const authenticateSpotify = () => {
    var axios = require('axios');

    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://is-authenticated/',
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxx'
      }
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I keep getting this error: ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '83zrpwubs673t3tb3bdz9xw4jlq49biq'.

But i'm not sure where exactly it's coming from.

There is currently no token in db so it should return False (which it does in Postman)

Not sure if this a backend or frontend problem. Can provide more code if it would help!

Been stuck on this for days. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please try logging your requests to check the posted data if any discrepancy in post data.

Answer (score 0):

configure the `CORS_HEADERS` according to this documentation.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didm't work. Im just not sure why its returning that long value for the field 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to access access_token not the user_id. smh